# need reference to use hyperledger fabric go sdk (fabric-sdk-go)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I am writing an application with Hyperledger Fabric.
I want to use `fabric-sdk-go` for which I need to write a config file which would be input to `fabsdk.New()`.

But I could not find any reference/materials on how to write that file, what parameters to use, how will parameters in that file be used by sdk instance generated by `fabsdk.New()` etc.

Could anyone please help me with this information? You could also share any online materials with the required information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config for SDK comes usually from a file called `config.yaml` that contains information about organizations, peers, channels and much more. For reference use [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/blob/master/test/fixtures/config/config_test.yaml) file or follow [this](https://chainhero.io/2018/03/tutorial-build-blockchain-app-2/#configuration) guide. Make sure your fabric-sdk-go branch and version match to the one you use the config you're using.

To initialize the sdk do something like `sdk, err := fabsdk.New(config.FromFile(ConfigFile))` where `ConfigFile` refers to file `"config.yaml"`, modify the path relative to the the location of where the `main.go` is run and where the file exists.

Always close the sdk with `sdk.Close()` when config changes and before reinitializing.

Comment: Is config file a must?? I want my network to be dynamic. i.e I may add new organisations to my network. So. for such a case I think a static config file wont help. Is such scenario possible with fabric??

Answer (score 0):

You can see examples in the integrations test of the sdk. One of them is the following:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/blob/master/test/integration/e2e/end_to_end.go

By navigating through the repository you can find any kind of example